# Is it possible to represent GPS time on an Arduino?

Tags: gps, arduino

I have a ubox GPS system that outputs the following on the occurrence of an event:

- wnR - GPS week number (two bytes)
- towMsR - Time of week in milliseconds (four bytes)
- towSubMsR - Millisecond fraction of tow in nanoseconds (four bytes)

It looks like to capture the time of the event in nanoseconds I have to use all eight bytes.
That puts it out of the range of the 16-bit Arduino.

Am I thinking about this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You can use two `unsigned long` variables for ms and ns (those won't be negative I presume) see the [Reference](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/UnsignedLong)